# Console App crashing after being launched from ASP.NET Webform

Tags: asp.net, process, console, exe

I need to trigger a Console App (exe) file from a asp.net webforms page. Obviously the main issue is permissions, and for now I'm just trying to get this working by letting the asp.net service impersonate the main Administrator account. Once I can get it working in a stable fashion, I'll set up it's own user and permissions. For now I would really appreciate assistance in getting this working.

Here's what I have.

Web Form Code.

```
Dim p As New Process()
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.FileName = locn & exeName
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
p.StartInfo.Arguments = GetTaskID
p.StartInfo.UserName = "adminuserid"
p.StartInfo.Domain = "domain"
Dim pw As New System.Security.SecureString
For Each ch As Char In "adminuserpassword"
   pw.AppendChar(ch)
Next
p.StartInfo.Password = pw
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "directory" 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = True
p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
```

Running this code from a button click event successfully launches the EXE, which I can see in the Process Manager on the server. However the process only runs for about 3 seconds and then closes.

The event log shows this information following the EXE crash/termination:

Application Error:
Faulting application BlueLimeConsoleApp.exe, version 1.0.0.0, time stamp 0x4d0ba5e2, faulting module KERNEL32.dll, version 6.0.6001.18000, time stamp 0x4791a7a6, exception code 0xc0000142, fault offset 0x00009cac, process id 0x10e8, application start time 0x01cb9e14d0c53e0c.

System Event:
Application popup: BlueLimeConsoleApp.exe - Application Error : The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000142). Click OK to terminate the application.

So, it seems as though I'm able to launch the EXE but it crashes for no apparent reason.

The code in the EXE is:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main(ByVal args As String())

        For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
            Console.WriteLine("hello world")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

In addition, I'm trying to capture the StandardError and StandardOutput messaging for testing purposes, and both return empty values.

Also, the EXE can be launched directly on the server via RDC and it runs just fine.

I've wasted almost 2 days trying to get this to work, and at this point I'm desperate for some experienced input on this job. I'd even be willing to throw in $50 as a thankyou gift to whoever has the solution!

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Also, launching CMD.exe from the webform generates the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a local computer or the server that ASP.NET is running on?

Comment: I'm trying to do this on my VPS which is running Windows 2008 Server with ASP.NET 3.5 and IIS7. I have full admin priviledges on the machine. All of this works fine on my local machine with VS2008.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you've already seen this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134

Comment: Yes I have, and followed suggestions on that page. Seeing the app run in the gui is not important, it just needs to run and complete without crashing.

Comment: How much of the stuff in `StartInfo` is actually important? If you strip all of that out can you still get a process to run? Trying to remove some of the variables to see if the problem is the IIS configuration (if you can launch Notepad as per the MSDN it should be fine), the process you are trying to run, or how you are launching it.

Comment: Bingo, once I removed everything except the following, it ran successfully under the Network Service user.  

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.FileName = locn & exeName
p.StartInfo.Arguments = GetTaskID 
p.Start()

I just have to give it a more secure user to run under. I may have some more questions, so keep an eye on this thread. Amazing how simple the solution is once you see it clearly! I'll pm you about the thankyo u gift! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rob, please contact me at todd[at]resonancemedia[dot]ca. Am new here, and can't find any PM mechanism.

Comment: @Todd Did you manage to run it under a more secure user without it crashing?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rob Z I was able to get this working, Once I removed everything except the following, it ran successfully under the Network Service user. Now I just need to run it with a more secure user.

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.FileName = locn & exeName
p.StartInfo.Arguments = GetTaskID 
p.Start()
```